# Why do I receive different results when I change <form> to <div>?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

There is a server made with Express.js and a signin.js form(using React) in which when you enter the right user information, you'll be directed to the home page.
The problem is that when form element is present in the following piece of code, as you enter user information, after being redirected to the home page it automatically return to the `signin.js` form.

When you change form element into div, everything works fine.

Plus, the request to server is made through 'Get', not as 'Post', as is specified in the code.

Here is the signin.js:

```js
import React from 'react';

class Signin extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      signInEmail: '',
      SignInPassword: ''
    }
  }

  onEmailChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ signInEmail: event.target.value })
  }

  onPasswordChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ signInPassword: event.target.value })
  }

  onSubmitSignIn = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/signin', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: this.state.signInEmail,
        password: this.state.signInPassword
      })
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (data === 'success') {
          this.props.onRouteChange('home');
        }
      })
  }

  render() {
    const { onRouteChange } = this.props;
    return (
      <article className="br3  ba  b--black-10 mv4 w-100 w-50-m w-25-l mw6 shadow-5 center">
        <main className="pa4 black-80">
          <div >
            <fieldset id="sign_up" className="ba b--transparent ph0 mh0">
              <legend className="f1 fw6 ph0 mh0">Sign In</legend>
              <form className="mt3">
                <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6" htmlFor="email-address">Email</label>
                <input
                  className="pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100"
                  type="email"
                  name="email-address"
                  id="email-address"
                  onChange={this.onEmailChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mv3">
                <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6" htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <input
                  className="b pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100"
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  id="password"
                  onChange={this.onPasswordChange}
                />
              </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div className="">
              <input
                onClick={this.onSubmitSignIn}
                className="b ph3 pv2 input-reset ba b--black bg-transparent grow pointer f6 dib"
                type="submit"
                value="Sign in"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="lh-copy mt3">
              <p onClick={() => onRouteChange('register')} className="f6 link dim black db pointer">Register</p>
            </div>
          </form>
        </main>
      </article>
    );
  }
}

export default Signin;
```

Comment: try `onSubmitSignIn = (e) => { e.preventDefault(); .... rest of your code ...}`

Comment: The default behaviour of [form tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) is to trigger a page refresh. You need to intercept the `onSubmit` of the form element and `preventDefault()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking a `type="submit"` button in a `form` submits the form; that's what submit buttons are for. Submitting a form sends the form data to the form's `action` URL (the same page if there is none), loading the result.

If you want to send the form data via ajax instead, you should either change that to `type="button"` or call `preventDefault` on the event object.